# why is this code not working and how to check if a table exist in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a database table when the page loads. I tried this code :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");

string user2 = Page.User.Identity.Name + "imgs";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ccmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE '" + user2 + "' (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,img VARCHAR(225))", conn2);
conn2.Open();
ccmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn2.Close();
```

...but it doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Also - How can I check if a table exists in the database?  I'm using asp.net 3.5

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - do you get an error or does it appear to succeed from the code but nothing happens in the database? If you do get an error what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this;

```
CREATE TABLE '" + user2 + "' 
(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) 
PRIMARY KEY,img VARCHAR(225))
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE " + user2 + " 
(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) 
PRIMARY KEY,img VARCHAR(225))
```

Comment: or use [ and ] around " + user2 + " instead of the quote if the OP feels strongly about the identifier

Answer (score 2):

To check if a table exists in MSSQL, you can use this (example table name is 'users'):

```
IF EXISTS 
(    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users'
) 
    DROP TABLE users;
```

...or do whatever it is you want to do with the table afterwards, not just drop it obviously.

Comment: do i need to add a namespace or add this within a sql command